# Unable to build Lightning Component source for markup://c:HelloWorldLightningWebComponent: Invalid suffix: json

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, lightning-web-components

I have created a project named "*HelloWorldLightningWebComponent*", and created a LWC component to it. While deploying the source to org from VSC, getting the error message. I have checked the version in both lwc's meta file and also sfdx-project.json file, its the same (45.0). Any ideas what is missing?

Also verified the source org for component with same name and didnt find any.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

```javascript
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0"
}
```

Comment: Please share the code, without that it's hard to tell what's wrong?

Comment: ye, and project structure if possible

Comment: @MohithShrivastava  Added the meta file and sfdx-project.json files.

Comment: @ytiq There is no change to project structure. Have created one as per trailhead module (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component)

Comment: @vignesh Can you reach out to me on mohith.shrivastava@salesforce.com

Answer (score 3):

JSON suffix error. It happened to me and I changed the repository name from "lwc" to "LWC" and solved the problem.

Comment: Additionally "lwc" should not be used as a name for any parent folder in the project path.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to be organized and created ~/dev/lwc and moved all of my existing apps into this dir. This is what caused the issue. As soon as I renamed ~/dev/lwc to ~/dev/SOMETHINGELSE, deploys started working again.

Comment: I filed an issue about this https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1395

Answer (score 2):

This error happens if you already have a Lightning Web Component in your instance with the same name that you are trying to create a new one.

Hence make sure to use a New org if you are doing a Trailhead or refresh all the components from your org using the [Org Browser](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser/) to make sure you are editing instead of adding a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I saved my project by mistake inside another projects's force-app\mian\default\lwc. Changed the location and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that was the cause but I accidently created the new project under main folder of another project and when I was trying to deploy I got this error . Later I deleted the new project folder and made separate folder and I was able to deploy the component .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Turns out it was a typo in my test folder name, I had an extra underscore in the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

for my situation, it seems cause by a experimental feature "salesforcedx-vscode-core.experimental.deployRetrieve". go to file > preference and disable deployRetrieve

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. In my case I had a folder named lwc in the navigation path to the actual location of the of the project. And I had another component at the same level as the correct one.
Once I removed the entire folder of the extra component and updated the lwc folder, I was able to get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same issue. It's because I tried to delete files in my current project and authorize/deply to org from there. Resolved when I created a new project for the new files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that none of the folders in the Project path has name "lwc". I faced this issue as well,  and fixed it by changing the name of a subfolder named "lwc" in the project-path to something else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had saved a .json file in the root folder for my LWC. Removing it solved the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful.

Was fortunate enough to catch a codebase with very similar metadata failing full package version creation complaining about "unable to build lightningcomponent..."

ended up being an adjustment to my .forceignore to include :

```
# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**
```

This is what was needed as an addition. I already had the below:

```
# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json
```